# TypeScript passing a function as a parameter: bind vs anonymous

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript I have a code snippet like this:

```js
private async predicate(some_parameter: string): Promise<boolean> {
           output = await api_call(some_parameter);
           return output !== undefined;
}
```

Now I can call it in two ways:

```js
await RepeaterUtil.monitor(this.predicate.bind(this, some_parameter));
```

```js
await RepeaterUtil.monitor(() => this.predicate(some_parameter));
```

Basically it will monitor till the time the predicate is not undefined (some value).

The question I have:

Although both are functionally working - which one is preferred (bind or calling anonymously) and why?

Purpose of the question:
Best possible way to write code following TypeScript rules (bestpractices).

Comment: They function the same and I even think they both output the same compiled javascript code. So it's just an opinion regarding which one is better.